# joomla multiads test with images

Tags: joomla

i have my joomla website on my localhost. i like to see how it looks like with ads. How can i do that ?

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/google-ads/4995/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Joomla install on localhost should be fully functional if you configured it correctly. Just install the extension and it should work.

Comment: how can i test weather it works ? is there some sort of test code to test my localhost site with images ?

Comment: MultiAds supports basically any HTML code for ads, just use a sample image. Or, if you have an account with any of the supported ad networks use that. It should work exactly as if it was a live site.

Comment: i added this jpeg image but only the link url is being displayed https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en_GB/images/banner.gif what can i do ?